# How to select uniqueidentifier in SQL

Tags: sql-server

Hi I have a uniqueidentifier column in table but cannot select it using

```
declare @PDRowID varchar(100)
set @PDRowID = N'10BFD29A-927D-42B7-8E5E-0FDF1043AB84'

SELECT 
    [NumRejects],
    [Delay],
    [MinBackColor],
    [MaxBackColor],
    [MinPercentage],
    [MaxPercentage],
    [PDRowID],
    [CriteriaDate],
    [SecToRefresh],
    [LastAccident]
 FROM USR_Eff_Criteria WHERE [PDRowID] = @PDRowID
```

whats wrong here?

Comment: What column type is `PDRowID`?

Comment: So @qazifarhan, based on your comments in the answer to Joel the 'problem' here was that the record you were trying to find had been deleted from the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the type of your variable like that:

```
DECLARE @PDRowID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
set @PDRowID = N'10BFD29A-927D-42B7-8E5E-0FDF1043AB84'
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: @qazifarhan Is there an error when you execute the query or simply no result?

Comment: no result no error. Sorry somebody delete this record. Thanks.

Comment: @qazifarhan Oky, and there is a result when you directly define the `WHERE` clause by hand like that: `WHERE [PDRowID] = N'10BFD29A-927D-42B7-8E5E-0FDF1043AB84'`?

Comment: @Lamak Just an habit when working in T-SQL, your remark is pertinent the `N` prefix is useless in this case.

Answer (score 0):

use this to work

```
SELECT 
    [NumRejects],
    [Delay],
    [MinBackColor],
    [MaxBackColor],
    [MinPercentage],
    [MaxPercentage],
    [PDRowID],
    [CriteriaDate],
    [SecToRefresh],
    [LastAccident]
 FROM USR_Eff_Criteria WHERE [PDRowID] =  '10BFD29A-927D-42B7-8E5E-0FDF1043AB84'
```